# Block all traffic to/from VPS when OpenVPN client isn't connected

Tags: firewall, openvpn, vps

So i have managed to setup an OpenVPN VPS. My public clientside IP is static.

For an abundance of security I'd like to automate a firewall blocking all traffic when the VPN client isn't connected. When client connects, traffic can flow so open up firewall.... Almost like a soft shutdown except purely a drop all unless from clientside static IP.

Any ideas how to implement this? I understand that I can't drop all incoming when I'm using it as a VPN server so realistically at present I can manually achieve this by firewall drop all from all type deal - I'd just prefer to automate.

Comment: deny all, allow myip and tun/tap but what would you like to reach with this?

Comment: I can do this but then the VPN server can't access anything but myip. I just want to auto deny all upon disconnect of vpn client. When reconnecting i want to open up again for the duration of the vpn session. I use vpn sporadically but it is public facing so I don't want to worry about it's hardening while online and open.